# Json.createBuilderFactory and createObjectBuilder hang

Tags: java, json, scala

I am attempting to create a simple JSON object using the `javax.json._` classes, however, the `createBuilderFactory()` and `createObjectBuilder()` methods hang when called. All of the below examples hang and neither reach the second `println()` call.

```
println("makeJson")
val jsonBuilder = Json.createBuilderFactory(null).createObjectBuilder()
println("madeJson")

println("makeJson")
val jsonBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder()
println("madeJson")

println("makeJson")
val jsonBuilderFactory = Json.createBuilderFactory(null)
println("madeJson")
```

Before executing the above examples, I don't do any setup regarding the Json classes.
What could the problem be?

Answer (score -1):

It's probably because you are using the javax.json api for compilation.
There is another one for running applications.

For more infos: https://jsonp.java.net/download.html

Comment: What do you mean by "using the javax.json api for compilation"?